# promql: how to do comparison of two vectors with different labels and values number?

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

Real life example. I'm trying to make query for alertmanager that will check if kafka consumer group is lagging, eg when lag metric is bigger than certain threshold from another metrics.

Right now my query is looking like this:

```sql
sum(kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum) by (consumergroup, topic) 
> on (consumergroup) group_left (consumergroup)
avg(catalog_component_kafka_alerts_limits{severity="info"}) by (consumergroup)
```

But the problem is that `catalog_component_kafka_alerts_limits` doesn't have all the consumergroups, so I need some kind of fallback. One solution is to wrap around `or` with the same query but with a literal in place of threshold:

```sql
(
  sum(kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum) by (consumergroup, topic) 
  > on (consumergroup) group_left (consumergroup)
  avg(catalog_component_kafka_alerts_limits{severity="info"}) by (consumergroup)
)
or
sum(kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum) by (consumergroup, topic) > 1000
```

It works, but looks ugly, and considering that it is not a full query and I also join some extra metadata (eg team label) with the same technique then this query become event more complicated and unmaintainable.

I want a solution to look something like this:

```sql
sum(kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum) by (consumergroup, topic) 
> on (consumergroup) group_left (consumergroup)
(avg(catalog_component_kafka_alerts_limits{severity="info"}) by (consumergroup) or vector(1000))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any "fallback" in Grafana needs usage of `or`.

Your "ugly" query besides having a small issue in syntax<sup>1</sup> has an additional problem: if `catalog_component_kafka_alerts_limits` for some `consumergroup` is more than 1000 (fallback value), for example 3000, and actual result is between that value and fallback threshold, for example 1500, then this query will still return result: first part will not return result for that `consumergroup` but second part of `or` will catch it up.

The correct approach for your case will be calculation of the threshold for every `consumergroup` and comparing actual values with it only afterwards.

This can be done with query like

```bash
sum by (consumergroup, topic) (kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum) 
> on (consumergroup) group_left ()
# Threshold calculation
(
  # Threshold from the provided metric
  # (looks a bit strange, but taken as is from your attempt)
  avg by (consumergroup) (catalog_component_kafka_alerts_limits{severity="info"})
  # if threshold metric for some consumergroup is not present 
  # it will be replaced with default value with correct label consumergroup attached
  or sum by (consumergroup) (kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum) * 0 + 1000
)
```

Here, construction `or sum by (somelabel) (somemetric) * 0 + N` is used to provide set of vectors with value `N` for every present value of label `consumergroup`.

This approach is not much prettier than your attempt, but at least it wouldn't require any duplication of code for metadata inclusion.

---

If provided query still doesn't make you feel warm and fuzzy, you can introduce [recording rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/), that will provide calculated value for thresholds in a similar fashion to what is done for inline calculation.

```yaml
- record: system:catalog_component_kafka_calculated_alert_limit
  expr: avg by (consumergroup) (catalog_component_kafka_alerts_limits{severity="info"}) or sum by (consumergroup) (kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum) * 0 + 1000
```

And then simply use query

```
sum by (consumergroup, topic) (kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum) 
> on (consumergroup) group_left () system:catalog_component_kafka_calculated_alert_limit
```

---

<sup>1</sup> : your usage of `group_left` is incorrect. It cannot contain same labels as the ones used in the `on` clause. I believe query that will match your intentions will be:

```
sum by (consumergroup, topic) (kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum) 
  > on (consumergroup) group_left ()
  avg by (consumergroup) (catalog_component_kafka_alerts_limits{severity="info"}) 
or sum by (consumergroup, topic) (kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum) > 1000
```

position of `by` clause doesn't affect anything, I just find it easier to comprehend query if it has those clauses upfront.

Comment: "has an additional problem" yeah, I figured it out yesterday, and gave up ... until noticed your answer, this is nice trick and it worked, I even was able to simplify other parts of the query

Comment: "group_left is incorrect" indeed, it is used to attach extra labels, so in my example it is redundant. But victoriametrics didn't throw an exception, so I didn't notice ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @aiven, glad my answer helped. `group_left()` with empty brackets preserves labels of LHS (at least in Prometheus), so it's very popular, and I can only assume beneficial for you too, as it will allow to show which topic is problematic. Regarding victoria - we have [tag:victoriametrics] tag, it's usually good idea to use it too (if you're using Victroia of course): while their devs claim compatibility with promql, there is a couple nuances in their implementations. Also a couple of their devs are active on SO, so it might increase visibility of your question and thus chance to get an answer.